# Kendo Grid strange horizontal scroll behavior with dynamic checkbox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-angular-ui

Reproduction  [[Stackblitz]](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3fcgtk?file=src/app/app.component.ts):

1. Click the "Toggle" button several times

The horizontal grid scroll will jump at the start/end.
It looks like the grid's input `[columnMenu]="{ filter: true }"` affects this.
If you delete this input, all works as expected and the scroll doesn't jump.

Any thoughts or help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a [known issue in kendo-angular](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/3453)

From the link above:

**Describe the bug**

When hiding a column will cause the page to scroll to the Grid position. The issue is related to v5.0.1 ( kb-nav: content is scrolled to the top when focusing a header cell ). Locking the column will also focus on the last header cell and scroll the Grid horizontally (reference 1573208).

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

open - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvszf5-fi8sx5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts
Press the hide column button
Expected behavior
Not losing focus and scrolling the Grid position

**Workaround**

The scroll can be disabled and re-enabled when pressing the button:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvszf5-jvbxlm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

A second workaround that keeps the horizontal scroll position of the Grid:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7xgsx2-jkc1wm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: True, thanks for the link! Btw now we also have one more ticket in StackOverflow :)

Comment: True, you can accept this as the answer so it doesn't show as an unanswered question any longer...